# Hiding status bar completely

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I hide the status bar in applicationDidFinishLaunching using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

That works fine except the status bar is there while the app is loading.  Meaning, when the default.png is displayed, I see the status bar.  Is there a way to have the status bar not show at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add UIStatusBarHidden to your info.plist file, set to true.  Documentation here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

and then open up the info.plist file, create a new line, chose **Status bar is initial hidden** and set it to true.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your Info.plist to include the entry "Status bar is initially hidden" and set the value to YES.

[image]

For more information:
http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/StatusBar.html